# C# Math Performance on Raw Memory Stream

Tags: c#, .net, performance, math

I'm considering writing a video processing library in C# instead of C++. C++ has the advantage of working with pointers on the raw video frame buffer. C# instead has a MemoryStream on that buffer that it can seek back and forth.

Mathematical formulas need to be applied to each pixel one by one; or 8 by 8 or 16 by 16 if using assembly optimization in C++.

How will doing this in C# compare to doing it in C++, or doing it with SSE2 assembly?

C# does have the advantage that it can use all CPU-specific instructions such as AVX and AVX2 because it does the final compilation on-the-fly, and how well does it do it?

Are there best-practices to get the best performance out of C# for such tasks?

Moving the cursor within a MemoryStream also makes the syntax more complex compared to a pointer. Are there ways to simplify this?

Edit: Based on comments here and elsewhere, there seems to be 2 options.

1. System.Numerics.Vectors
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879696(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4
2. NumPy and SciPy are popular options for such work in Python, and have been ported into .NET
   https://www.infoq.com/news/2011/07/NumPy-NET

Any ideas about the pros, cons and limitations of these 2 options? Does System.Numerics.Vectors work with x86 only x64? Does SciPy use SIMD optimization?

If performance close to C++ SIMD can be obtained in C# without having to write several versions of the same function (C++, SSE2, AVX), this would have great advantages. It would allow for SIMD optimizations in places that wouldn't use it otherwise.

Edit2: Nowhere can I read that NumPy and SciPy support SIMD optimization, so System.Numerics.Vectors is the way to go.

Comment: C# supports pointers too in `unsafe` contexts, but performance is worse than C++ due to lack of support for SSE.

Comment: Anything is possible, but you are competing with existing codec implementations that were very carefully hand-tuned over many years.  Only consider doing this if you have years available as well.

Comment: This is for the development of AviSynth plugins using .NET. There's a whole community of programmers developing such plugins; mostly in C++ and assembly.
http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=144663

Answer (score 2):

SIMD instructions are only supported with [a few data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879696(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4), the types ship with .NET 4.6 or you can use the [System.Numerics.Vectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors) NuGet package to get it on .NET 4.5.

Honestly, if you are experienced writing SSE2 assembly or SIMD C++ code you will likely have much better performance with those and should stick with whichever one you have most experience with.

Comment: I have no experience with SIMD programming; I wrote a C++ piece of code and someone else had to add that part. He also used intrinsics for AVX conversion to/from 16-bit float, but the downside is that an assembly compiled with AVX support only works with AVX-capable CPUs and I must deploy 4 DLL versions: x86, x64, x86-AVX, x64-AVX.

Comment: "your 64-bit apps must be compiled by the new 64-bit JIT Compiler for managed code" Does this mean SIMD won't be used with x86 compilation?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I have never personally used System.Numerics.Vectors